# jquery onclick submit not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to stackoverflow.

I am using jQuery for an application. Because of some reasons the onclick submit is not working to change the color of the submit button.

Here's a minimal demonstration of my problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type='submit']").onClick(function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
    });
});
```

```css
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="blue">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using...

```js
   
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-form').on('submit', function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
    });
  });
```

Using this code above is specifically for form submission rather then using the `.click`. If you do use this, you will also have to specify `.` or `#` for in front of your `my-form` element as it is declared in your html like so..`#my-form` or `.my-form` depending on if it is a class (`.`) or a id (`#`)

Comment: This is incomplete.. You will need to specify an ID to the form ie:  `id="my-form"`.. And use `$('#my-form')` Please give full answers.